# How do I send a file to an old pen plotter using a USB to centronics cable with Windows 11, ideally through DOS?

Tags: usb, windows-11, ms-dos

I have an old Graphtec pen plotter from the 90's that works perfectly well from ubuntu copying files via the terminal. It also used to work with windows 10 but I can no longer communicate with it via windows 11, any help would be appreciated. Obviously there are no modern drivers but I would have thought a generic text driver or any HPGL one would work.

Comment: Windows 11 is quite different from Windows 10. If all else fails, maybe mount a Windows 10 VM , send the file to Windows 10 (Windows 11 and 10 do network) and print from Windows 10 .

Comment: Thanks for the rapid reply John, I will look into your suggestion. It is certainly more difficult than I was expecting. It works perfectly on a Linux platform so all is not lost. Perhaps I should ask AI to write me a driver :-)